# MSBuild publish stopped working out of nowhere

Tags: deployment, msbuild

For a very long time the following command worked as expected:

```
msbuild /property:Configuration=Release /property:TransformConfigFiles=true /property:DeployOnBuild=true /property:PublishProfile=FolderProfile /verbosity:normal /target:Rebuild /fileLogger /nologo /m Ticket.Corporativo.sln
```

By "expected" I mean, the project is built, then "packaged" into a "pkg" folder according to a publish profile called "FolderProfile" which is a simple file system deployment.

The last time it worked as expected was 2019-01-30. On the daily build of the 31st, the 'pkg' folder of "FolderProfile" was no longer created. Checking the build server, nothing we could track was changed... no updates, no nothing!

I've run out of ideas or items to check that could explain this failure... can anyone help?

PS:
-MSBuild version is 14.0
-Project being built
-Works on local machine as expected

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out: Apparently, on my local machine, I added a reference to a package that was not available in our internal NUGET (only available on the public NUGET), which is the only source the builder machine has access... that caused an error, but was not reported as such, it failed silently... after copying the nuget pack to out server, it worked again perfectly

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Are you serious?!? Did you notice that i answered my own question?!?!?

Comment: Yes, but this is the situation: **Why my complex `msbuild` command with a special output folder and more details not work?** -- *The build failed*. it's obvious. (Although the build failed because *nuget* things. The next person that use your `msbuild` command to build in server, and it will didn't work for him, his problem will be in *public nuget*?